# Finding a stable conjugate base when comparing nitrogen vs. a triple bond

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I am trying to understand acid-base reactions and I am trying to figure out which conjugate base is more stable.

[image]

The molecule on the top with dashed lines around the $\ce{H}$ is the original molecule and then below it I remove $\ce{H}$ and see what the resultant conjugate base looks like. I don't understand why the bottom left conjugate base is less stable than the one on the right.  Why doesn't nitrogen create a more stable conjugate base than the triple bond?

Comment: Maybe it's due to geometry? The triple bonded C has a single lone pair to donate, while the N has two. So that would allow a wider range of acceptable orientations when considering N-/H+ collisions?

Comment: Hey, just so you know, the homework tag is [being phased out](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/do-we-really-need-homework-part-3?cb=1), so please don't tag questions with it. Thanks!

Comment: @heather thanks! I won't do that from now on.

Comment: @DanBurden could you elaborate some more?

Comment: Well I think the crux of this lies in the fact that ammonia has pKa 33 while ethyne has 25, which you can apply here. Why is it so, because I guess a sp carbon is more electronegative than a sp3 nitrogen perhaps.

Comment: @Sawarnik I see that pKa is greater for ammonia, but I guess what about sp carbon makes it more electronegative than an sp3?

Comment: Well you know that sp carbon is quite a bit more electronegative than a sp3 carbon right? Now why exactly it exceeds that of sp3 nitrogen is something i don't know, or perhaps I may be entirely wrong here.